# Strange errors building the data-default package

Tags: windows, haskell, cabal

I'm getting a number of strange error messages while trying to `cabal install data-default`. The same basic phenomenon happens for that package even in a fresh sandbox. I can install other packages with no problem.

The error messages are of the following form, but occur for each of the 4 `data-default-instances-` packages:

`[1 of 1] Compiling Data.Default.Instances.OldLocale ( Data\Default\Instances\OldLocale.hs, dist\dist-sandbox-6a114df1\build\Data\Default\Instances\OldLocale.o )
C:\Program Files (x86)\MinGHC-7.10.1\ghc-7.10.1\mingw\bin\ar.exe: dist/dist-sandbox-6a114df1\build\libHSdata-default-instances-old-locale-0.0.1-6jcjjaR25tK4x3nJhHHjFM.a-8696\libHSdata-default-instances-old-locale-0.0.1-6jcjjaR25tK4x3nJhHHjFM.a: No such file or directory`

Any idea what's going on?

#### Output from `ghc-pkg check`

```
C:\Users\Doug\Documents\GitHub\bird-brain [estimator]> ghc-pkg check
WARNING: cache is out of date: C:/Program Files (x86)/MinGHC-7.10.1/ghc-7.10.1\lib\package.conf.d\pa
ckage.cache
ghc will see an old view of this package db. Use 'ghc-pkg recache' to fix.
Warning: haddock-interfaces: C:\Users\Doug\AppData\Roaming\cabal\doc\i386-windows-ghc-7.10.1\QuickCh
eck-2.8\html\QuickCheck.haddock doesn't exist or isn't a file
Warning: haddock-html: C:\Users\Doug\AppData\Roaming\cabal\doc\i386-windows-ghc-7.10.1\QuickCheck-2.
8\html doesn't exist or isn't a directory
Warning: haddock-interfaces: C:\Users\Doug\AppData\Roaming\cabal\doc\i386-windows-ghc-7.10.1\tf-rand
om-0.5\html\tf-random.haddock doesn't exist or isn't a file
Warning: haddock-html: C:\Users\Doug\AppData\Roaming\cabal\doc\i386-windows-ghc-7.10.1\tf-random-0.5
\html doesn't exist or isn't a directory
Warning: haddock-interfaces: C:\Users\Doug\AppData\Roaming\cabal\doc\i386-windows-ghc-7.10.1\random-
1.1\html\random.haddock doesn't exist or isn't a file
Warning: haddock-html: C:\Users\Doug\AppData\Roaming\cabal\doc\i386-windows-ghc-7.10.1\random-1.1\ht
ml doesn't exist or isn't a directory
Warning: haddock-interfaces: C:\Users\Doug\AppData\Roaming\cabal\doc\i386-windows-ghc-7.10.1\primiti
ve-0.5.4.0\html\primitive.haddock doesn't exist or isn't a file
Warning: haddock-html: C:\Users\Doug\AppData\Roaming\cabal\doc\i386-windows-ghc-7.10.1\primitive-0.5
.4.0\html doesn't exist or isn't a directory
Warning: haddock-interfaces: C:\Users\Doug\AppData\Roaming\cabal\doc\i386-windows-ghc-7.10.1\mtl-2.2
.1\html\mtl.haddock doesn't exist or isn't a file
Warning: haddock-html: C:\Users\Doug\AppData\Roaming\cabal\doc\i386-windows-ghc-7.10.1\mtl-2.2.1\htm
l doesn't exist or isn't a directory
```

Comment: What is the output of `ghc-pkg check`?

Comment: Added output from ghc-pkg check. Attempted to follow it's hint about ghc-pkg recache, but that didn't seem to help. (Didn't even make the hint go away.)

Comment: Possibly related to this bug: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/10205

Comment: I don't know if that thing with the cache being out of date is actually the cause of your not being able to compile `data-default`, though. You might try `cabal install old-locale`. You may need to add `--reinstall` and/or `force-reinstalls`.

Comment: `--reinstall` doesn't change anything. I thought it might have to do with the maximum path length, but it turns out that the fully expanded path only has 223 characters (the limit is 260). Now I'm wondering if it has to do with the / vs \ war.

Comment: If you're still getting this error, I managed to get this to work by using `cabal install data-default -j1` in my sandbox. If that doesn't work, try `cabal get` for the package and then doing an install with `-j1 -force-reinstall`

Comment: Thanks @TheCriticalImperitive. I tried both of those things and got the same error messages. This problem is very strange.

Comment: Try doing a `cabal update` as I think the issue might be resolved now. I just built a sandbox which had data-default as a dependency and it installed without trouble.

Comment: The last new version was uploaded to hackage in 2013. And there is only one version at all up there for the child packages that are actually failing. I also tried copying the whole thing to a top level directory on my hard drive to get shorter paths just in case that really was the problem, no change.

Comment: Actually I can get the strategy at https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/2525 to work if I do it exactly as stated there, my previous try was a slightly different route.

Comment: @DougMcClean since you found a solution, do you mind posting it as an answer to this question so others can refer to it more easily if they encounter similar issues?

Answer (score 1):

Using the strategy at https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/2502 it is possible to fix this problem, which ultimately has to do with the Windows limit on overall path length.

Using stack is another solution, probably one to try first, because it internally uses a folder that is likely to be close enough to the root for the path to work.